# FFMPEG with Android SDKS 16-25 and NDK 14 - 'atof' error

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, ndk-build, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile FFMPEG (version 3.2.4) via NDK along with my android app.

Currently I have a compatibility issue with older devices.

I am able to compile if I use:

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
```

in the Application.mk but I am unable to load the library due to this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:    88 cannot locate 'atof'.
```

If I set the the APP_PLATFORM to android-16 I can't compile and receive this error:

```
   error: undefined reference to 'atof'
```

Any suggestions?  The SDK levels are a requirement so I am not able to drop support :(

Comment: File a bug please: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/new

Comment: Please note that clean rebuild is required when you switch APP_PLATFORM